# What is the correct cast to Collections.sort()?

Tags: java

I have a list of objects that I wish to sort but only if the list's generic type conforms to `java.util.Comparable`. I'm not sure what the correct cast is though:

```
private <T extends Widget> void doAction(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list) {
    if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
    // Do more.
}
```

`Collections.sort` requires the type parameter to implement `java.util.Comparable`, So I tried the following which all do not work:

```
Collections.sort((List<? extends Comparable<T>>)list);
Collections.sort((List<? extends Comparable>)list);
Collections.sort((List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>)list);
Collections.sort((List<T extends Comparable<? super T>>)list);
```

And anything else, I was really just guessing. I thought the first would have worked.

Any assistance is appreciated.

**UPDATE**: To show how this does not work the following error is raised from the compiler:

```
com/mycompany/test/WidgetTest.java:[112,20] no suitable method found for sort(java.util.List<T>)
    method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
        inferred: T
        bound(s): java.lang.Comparable<? super T>)
```

Note, that `Widget` does not conform to `Comparable`, that's intended, but a subclass of `Widget` may conform which is what I'm trying to test for.

Comment: I just tested your code in Eclipse but I don't get any error messages. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Sebastian - I've added the compiler message. Note that `Widget` does not confirm to `Comparable` but `Box extends Widget implements Comparable<Box>` should be allowed to be sorted which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: This is one of those cases where it is much easier just to use the raw version of Comparable - `Collections.sort(((List<Comparable>) list));`.

Comment: @Perception, see [my answer to Evgeniy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15629137/140037) how this does not work, a cast to `(List)` does work though.

Comment: @BrettRyan - now that is interesting. Because a `List<Object` cast works in Java 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
private <T extends Widget> void doAction(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list) {
    if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        Collections.sort((List)list);
    }
}
```

Comment: No go - `invonvertible types; required: List<Comparable>, found: List<T> where T is a type-variable - T extends Widget`.

Comment: There's the ticket, please update your answer so I can accept. For what it's worth I'm using jdk1.7.0_15 on OS X.

Comment: Though valid, static analysis may be unhappy about the raw use of a parameterized (generic) type. In IntellJ you can suppress this with a hint such as `/** @noinspection rawtypes, unchecked */` The IDE will typically hint these suppressions for you and they may vary by analysis tool :)

Answer (score 0):

as T is declared as extends Widget, you cannot cast List to List because it is simply incompatible.

I believe you can do a extremely ugly casting like `(List<Comparable>)(List)list` but it looks so horrible.

I'd recommend you make a dummy `Comparator`, which will cast the input object as Comparable and do the comparison directly.  So that you can simply do  `Collections.sort(list, new PassThroughComparator());`